# There is "Run Configuration" but no "Run As Scala Application" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have the following Scala class, I am able to run it from command line 
 by first typing sbt then in sbt mode. But I am not able to run it from eclipse .
I am already in scala perspective.

```
> run-main bcomposes.twitter.QuerySearch #IPL


package bcomposes.twitter

import twitter4j._
import collection.JavaConversions._

/**
 * Gets a Twitter instance set up and ready to use.
 */
trait TwitterInstance {
  val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance
}

/**
 * Given a command line query, search for tweets and print
 * them.
 */
object QuerySearch extends TwitterInstance {

  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    val statuses = twitter.search(new Query(args(0))).getTweets
    statuses.foreach(status => println(status.getText + "\n"))
  }

}
```

Comment: "I am not able to run it from eclipse" - Why not? Did you try? What happened? Did you get error messages?

Comment: Right-click in the editor that contains your Scala source code with the `main` method, choose Run As / Scala Application.

Comment: When I do a right click , I see Run As -> Run Configuration and not Run As Scala Application

Comment: may be you didn't write the main method or extends App: `object Hello extends App{}` (or) `def main(args : Array[String])`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the package name you specified under which your scala object file is added matches the package name you mentioned in your code. So, correct this and then check, "Run as Scala Application" should be available now

Answer (score 1):

Your Scala file has to be a part of Scala project. 
**Create Scala project using Scala Project wizard, add your file to it and try again.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to click right button on the Scala object with `main` method (not on the root project element). Then the "Run as... Scala application" menu item appears.

Answer (score 0):

"Run as Scala application" will show in Eclipse Scala IDE only if we extends the Scala object with  'APP' class.

Example:

```
package grreter
object Exp extends App{
  println("Hello, New World!")
}
```

(Note: if you comment "extends App" then 'Run As Scala Application' will not show.)

Answer (score -1):

The way I solve this problem is using maven to compile and package the project , when the maven build  is correct, the "run as scala application" appear again.